# Maintain Socket Connection for React native project in Application state (active , inactive , background)

Tags: react-native, sockets, signalr

I'm working on a react native project I want to create a socket connection to interact with the server the aim of the connection is track user location and to send specific events when action required ,
What I was expecting is the socket to stay alive as long as the application isn't terminated
but the connection were killed if the application was inactive or the phone is locked so the OS is terminating all the TCP connection

is there a way to keep  the connection as long as the application isn't terminated or what alternative solution we have for the case

- Background fetch doesn't work because in IOS i can send an event every 15 minute minimum
- Previously I was using Background Geolocation it was working fine but not always and for long term like 8 hours

Thanks :)

I want to maintain the socket connection even if the Mobile is in lock screen or application in background
for the connection I'm using SignalR

Comment: Any router or the peer can drop the connection at any time. Instead of trying to make this impossible, which you can't, you should be trying to make your program robust against it, which means detecting the dropped connection, closing the socket, and creating a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing your own ping/pong your websocket server every 30seconds or so (it depends on your server configuration) to maintain the connection?

I am no expert on mobile but I feel like the problem is the same on web: after a specific Idle time of no traffic being sent to your websocket server, connection closes.

Comment: I have implemented the ping/pong but the thing is once Iphone screen is locked instant connection closed or Samsung looks like for security reasons Iphone and Samsung doesn't allow you to perform Tcp connection if the phone is inactive

Answer (score 0):

For tracking one thing we can do is to track data and save in localstorage using watch position

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).